# Where to find the rules for Abilities for Alola and Galar Pokémon?

Tags: pokemon-tabletop-united

Though the main Dex for 1.05 does not include the Alolan and Galar Dex, I have found files for these that are- As far as I am aware, official. However, some Pokémon included in these have abilities that are unique to them and are thus not described in the 1.05 core rulebook.
For now, I am (wherever possible) assuming that these are identical to the abilities in the main game with the same name. However, I would like to know the official PTU rulings of these abilities. Where could I find these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### They are in separate documents

The official [Gen 7](https://www.tapatalk.com/groups/pokemon_tabletop/gen-7-pokedex-t5995.html) and [Gen 8](https://www.tapatalk.com/groups/pokemon_tabletop/gen-8-pokedex-t7257.html#p209522) announcement tapatalk pages include links to the [SuMo Reference Document](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1J0B6RPyeY3kD_g74FKvJqEoHxFfrR6a1/view) and the [SwSh Reference Document](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WnUYmaNzy_I6JSniortS3iPrfTA2D-9S/view) which include the explanations for new Keyword, Capabilities, Abilities, and Moves and notes any of those that were updated.